# ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

I'm using in my `index.js` file this:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
```

I have this index.js file imported to my `index.html`

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

If I open the index.html file in browser, everything works fine.

However, if I try to use `node index.js` or `nodemon index.js` command, I get an error.

```
ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined
```

I can see in the vscode IDE that Filereader is from '`lib.dom.d.ts`' and if I type to chrome inspect console 'FileReader' I can see that it exists. It seems to be bundled with chrome.

Is there a way I could bundle this file to index.js so that I can run `node index.js` or `nodemon index.js`? Or am I approaching this the wrong way? Should I use some other package instead of FileReader? The purpose is to use the package in the browser to read a file.

Comment: You are trying to use `FileReader` in nodejs? In node you want to use `fs`

Comment: There is no other way? I want to use nodemon so that when I refresh I wouldn't have to build everything again and refresh the page

Comment: If you want the code to be used in both environments, You can detect if FileReader is defined, if not use fs or a library that recreates FileReader. I am not sure how you are reading a file in node and the same file in the browser. I think we need more details on how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly and I'm doing something wrong, I'm using browserify npm package to bundle all the dependencies into index.js and it's a static site. I was trying to avoid the situation of having to check for environment, but I guess there's no other way If I want to use nodemon.